# VHDL Product of two natural numbers

Tags: vhdl

I am writing small code for perfection. 
Can i implement arithmetic of two natural number like 1223 (-,+,*,/ 4455??
I have tried implementing arithmetic operations on small number by converting them to binary, but what in the case of big digits??
Is there any thing I can try doing??
All your suggestions will be helpful..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a very basic question; please start with some tutorial! however, here's a very basic example:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity SIMPLE is
Port ( 
    a : in  integer;
    b : in  integer;
    c : out  integer
);
end SIMPLE;

architecture Behavioral of SIMPLE is

begin
    c<=a*b;
    -- c<=a-b;
    -- c<=a+b;
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Can you suggest me a best site?